# PHP - Save image inside a div into a file

Tags: php, html, post, get, save

I'm having a problem with a feature for a website.
After having modified an uploaded photo, I need to grab the image from my HTML page and:

1. save it to a folder on my server (for the moment is on local);
2. save the path in the DB.

While the second part is pretty simple, I can't understand how to save the photo to a folder. I've managed to do it with a file taken from an input form (using $_FILES[][]), but I can't understand how to use $_POST or $_GET to do the same with an online file.

Here is my image div

```
<div class="cropped" name="avatar"></div>
```

which is filled by this function

```
$('#btnCrop').on('click', function () {
  var img = cropper.getDataURL();

  if ($('.cropped').is(':empty')) {
    $('.cropped').append('<img id="crop" name="crop" src="' + img + '">');
    } else {
    $('.cropped').html('<img id="crop" name="crop" src="' + img + '">');
}
```

I'm trying to use this PHP function, but I can't manage to let it work:

```
file_put_contents("file.png", file_get_contents("data://" . $_POST['crop']));
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

I've forgot to say I've a submit button in my HTML code:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="avatar" method="post" action="">
<div class="avatarContainer">
    <div class="imageBox">
        <div class="thumbBox"></div>
        <div class="spinner" style="display: none">Caricamento...</div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <div class="action">
            <span class="file-input btn btn-primary btn-file">
                Sfoglia<input id="file" type="file">
            </span>
            <button id="btnZoomIn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
            <button id="btnZoomOut" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">-</button>
            <button id="btnCrop" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ritaglia</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <center>
        <div class="cropped" name="avatar"></div>
    </center>
</div>
<br>
<input class="btn btn-default btn-upload" type="submit" value="Cambia">
</form>
```

Comment: You will either need an url of a file, so you can download it using the script (provided it is accessible from the server on which PHP runs), or the client (browser) needs to post the file to the server so the script can process it. You cannot just grab an image from an img element in the browser. There is no direct interaction between PHP and the browser.

Comment: I've forgot to say that I'm already using a submit button to post the content of the form in which the button and the image are restraint.
Still, I can't manage to make it work.

Comment: `copy()` / `rename()`?

Comment: So the image is already in a form? apply this form tag:  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` try var_dumping that.

Comment: Yep, it is. I'll modify my original post with the whole code.

Comment: You need to make an input field too, because the image is an `<img>` and not an `<input>` PHP will ignore it. You could always make an hidden input field with the path as value and open it after you submit. Although the file must be on the server, or else(as GolezTrol says) they need to upload it manually

Comment: Ok. I think I'll go for the second solution: give users the opportunity to crop their profile images, download them and THEN reupload the new one.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use a library like [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), or at least peek to learn how they did it. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol, yep, I've been already using something similar.
Thanks for your message. :)